# iPhone MPMoviePlayer obtain buttons view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, controls, mpmovieplayer

Can anyone suggest me how to obtain the view that contains all buttons from 'MPMoviePlayer'?

If you don't know, at least how you obtain the main view/window of the MPMoviePlayer.

**UPDATE:** I need to do this to add a button on the controller view. It would look something like this:
[Example http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/5184/poz.jpg](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/5184/poz.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can provide much better help if you tell us what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Can anyone give any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add it directly to the MPMoviePlayerController's view -- that's a private view and isn't accessible. If you want to add buttons, you need to create a transparent window over the top of everything and add the buttons to that.

Apple's [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798) sample shows how to do this.

Comment: The screenshot above is from an app from the AppStore.

Comment: Till, if you're going to pay more attention, you'll se that the 'seek' button in on the bar, not in a separated window. When the Controls disappear, the button disappear. Also, the Next/Prev buttons are disabled.

Comment: MPMovieControlModeHidden + custom overlay window resembling the original interface

Comment: mxg... the seek button is not on the bar. It's in a separate, invisible window floating over the bar that fades out when the NSNotification indicating the controls are disappearing is sent.

It *looks* like its in the bar but that's just due to careful placement.

Comment: To reinforce my point -- look extremely closely at the gloss gradient brightness on the "Seek" button. Notice that it's different to the zoom button -- because the "Seek" button is not drawn at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is actually incorrect: the view is not private, and you can add views to it. You just have to dive deep enough to find it.

For example, in iOS 5.1, you can try something like this:

```
UIView *fullscreenOverlayView = [[[[[[[mpPlayer view] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
[fullscreenOverlayView addSubview:ccButton];
```

This will add a CC button to the view, and if you specify the correct value for the frame of the CC button, it will insert the button to the control panel, and hide/show it with the control panel on touch. FYI: this is the frame I use:

```
BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);

// all of these values are just based on measurement on screen
// to make sure that the CC button "seems" to be part of the player's control panel
if (isPortrait)
{
    return CGRectMake(222, 880, 40, 40);
}
else {
    return CGRectMake(350, 625, 40, 40);
}
```

NOTE: the set of subviews of [mpPlayer view] are different for different iOS versions, so consider this as a work around only. There's no guarantee that this will work on iOS 6, and will crash on iOS 4.3.

Comment: Just to clarify, the fullscreenOverlayView is actually the view that contains all the control buttons.